# How to decline a job offer because of distance?

Tags: professionalism, hiring-process

I just got a job offer at location A, which is over an hour from where I live and I am not willing to relocate or drive that far. What would be a proper way to decline (in an email)? I don't want to completely shoot it down because they may have offices closer to where I live, or know other recruiters closer to where I live who are looking for people of my skill set.

Comment: Is it an offer or an invitation to apply. If it is an offer, did you know the location when you applied and interviewed?

Comment: When I applied the location posted was where I thought I lived, but then it was actually elsewhere, they want me to come in and fill out papers. We had multiple phone interviews and emails and I took online tests to prove my skill.

Comment: Are there multiple locations for this company? If so, you could say that you would be interested if a position opens up near you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

"Thank you for your time and interest, but upon further consideration I have decided that I would rather not relocate at this time. If you know of openings closer to [location] that you feel I would be well suited for, I would welcome a referral."

Saying what you mean, clearly and politely, is usually the best answer.